# Object accessed through queryset doesn't have the attributes in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following three models. Every `Record` can have many `User`s and each `Record` has a `Resource`. Granted I could be doing something grossly wrong here, but I still can't find the error.

```py
class Resource(models.Model):
    identifier = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Resource: {self.identifier}, Time added: {self.date_added}'

class URLResource(Resource):
    url = models.URLField()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.identifier} URL: {self.url}'


class Record(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    resource = models.OneToOneField(Resource, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Record {{ User: {self.user}, Resource: {self.resource} }}'
```

Here's the behavior that I get in my django shell

```py
>>> user = ... # a valid user

In [89]: {each for each in Record.objects.filter(user=user)}
Out[89]: 
{Record { User: dave, Resource: Resource object (9) },
 Record { User: dave, Resource: Resource object (11) },
 Record { User: dave, Resource: Resource object (12) }}

In [90]: {each.resource for each in Record.objects.filter(user=user)}
Out[90]: 
{Resource: 044565d1-9ddd-46a0-ae66-829253b45dd9, Time added: 2021-03-28 17:28:25.252009+00:00,
 Resource: 0ef18b7d-32f6-48c8-9c61-99f02ba6b6a9, Time added: 2021-03-28 19:08:06.178725+00:00,
 Resource: b4bb69ba-6f41-4c25-8999-d381d923890e, Time added: 2021-03-28 11:45:21.232911+00:00}
```

Something that doesn't work (but should work)

```py
# I get an error!!!
In [91]: {each.resource.url for each in Record.objects.filter(user=user)}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-1a5c17d5d743> in <module>
----> 1 {each.resource.url for each in Record.objects.filter(user=user)}

<ipython-input-91-1a5c17d5d743> in <setcomp>(.0)
----> 1 {each.resource.url for each in Record.objects.filter(user=user)}

AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'url'
```

My current hack which I dislike (but it works)

```py
# However, this works fine
In [94]: {URLResource.objects.get(id=each.resource.id).url for 
                              each in Record.objects.filter(user=user)}
Out[94]: {'apple.com', 'google.com', 'mit.edu'}
```

Clearly the last query is long and inefficient, but why does the normal i.e. the first query not work?

Comment: `{each.resource.urlresource for each in Record.objects.filter(user=user)}`

Comment: Wow! it works. Can someone please explain why it works, or is it common knowledge in the community?